# Newbie Question: How to use `form_tag` helper in Rails 3 to create a simple Contact Us form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

How would I use `form_tag` (because I don't have a model) to create a contact us form with a name, email, and message field. Then on submit I would like to call a controller action that would send an email to an email account. Sorry I'm new to Rails, but can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check here , i have googled to it and read briefly , but seems to be all OK!
http://www.railsmine.net/2010/03/rails-3-action-mailer-example.html

Have a nice day!

edit: ... in this example they use a model to store support message , it's a good idea , you have strong activerecord validation , a restfull action and an history of every message sent.

sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped a lot! (And your English is fine lol).

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Rails Engine https://github.com/jdutil/contact_us that you can easily drop into any Rails 3+ application.  I didn't add a Name field to the form, but you could fork the repo then modify it to suit your needs.  Or you can simply review the code to snag any relevant pieces you are stuck on for making your own form.  It does require the Formtastic gem since I wanted an easy way to hook into peoples existing form styles though.

To install the Engine add the contact_us gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'contact_us', '~> 0.0.8'
```

Run bundle and the install rake task:

```
$ bundle
$ bundle exec rake contact_us:install
```

Then just modify the generated initializer in /config/initializers/contact_us.rb to have the email you want the form submissions sent to.